# How to get and pass the last id# of the first set of results to another function to get next set with Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, api, google-apps-script, pagination, shopify-api

I am trying to figure out why I keep getting the following error:
ReferenceError: getLastID is not defined
callAPI @ callAPI.gs:62
getTenderTransactions @ callAPI.gs:13

I am able to get the last id# from the first batch of 250, but when it tries to get the last id# for the second run it fails?

```
function getTenderTransactions() {
  const root = 'https://<url address>'
  const endpoint = 'tender_transactions.json?'
  const recordCount = 'limit=250&'
  const startDate = 'processed_at_min=2022-01-01+00:01:00+-0600&'
  const endDate = 'processed_at_max=2022-02-31+23:59:00+-0600'
  const url = root + endpoint + recordCount + startDate + endDate
  const firstBatch = callAPI(url, 0, params)

  pasteArrayIntoSheet(SPREADSHEET_ID, firstBatch, "Copy of tender transactions")}

function callAPI(url, lastNumber, params) {
  let idNumber = '&since_id=' + lastNumber
  while (lastNumber != -1) {
    let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + idNumber, params)
    let responseCode = response.getResponseCode() // 200 response code OK  
    let data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText())
    let totalTenderTransactions = []

    if (responseCode === 200) {
    const results = data.tender_transactions
  //loop over the results
      results.forEach(row => {

      // get data elements of object
      const id = row.id
      const order_id = row.order_id
      const amount = row.amount
      const date = row.processed_at
      const paymentMethod = row.payment_method

      //push data into an array
      totalTenderTransactions.push([id, order_id, amount, date, paymentMethod])
  })
    let getlastID = totalTenderTransactions[totalTenderTransactions.length - 1][0]
    console.log('last ID in call - ' + getlastID)
    if (totalTenderTransactions.length < 250) {
    lastNumber = -1
  }
  else {
    lastNumber = getLastID
    console.log(lastNUmber)
    idNumber = '&since_id=' + lastNumber
    console.log(idNumber)

    return totalTenderTransactions
  }

  } else {
  console.log("Error: " + responseCode)
    }
  }
 }

// paste array into sheets
function pasteArrayIntoSheet(id, arrayName, sheetName) {

// get the sheet
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id)
const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName)

// get the range and paste in data
sheet.getRange(2, 1, arrayName.length, arrayName[0].length).setValues(arrayName)
}
```

Comment: Does the API return a nextPageToken?

Comment: @Cooper the API returns a link header 
( Link: "<https://{shop}.myshopify.com/admin/api/{version}/products.json?page_info={page_info}&limit={limit}>; rel={next})
The link header includes a rel parameter value can either be previous or next.

The issue is when a request that includes the page_info parameter can't include any other parameters except for limit and fields (if it applies to the endpoint). I don't know if it is possible to filter by other parameters (start & end dates) in the first request? That is why I thought using the id# may be a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updates I made to the code that is now working for me. Thanks to those who helped me understand coding concepts a bit better.

```
length = 250
let flag = true

while (flag) {
//set last number as last id from array batch
lastNumber = getLastItem()
console.log('while statement last id - ' + lastNumber)

//call API and pass parameters
newArray = getDataFunction(url, lastNumber, params)
console.log('newArray - ' + JSON.stringify(newArray))

//check if batch array is 250 or less
if (newArray.data.length == 0) {
  flag = false
  console.log('no more rows')
  break
} else {
  //get next batch returned
  let allTenderTransactions = newArray.data
  console.log('updatedArray - ' + allTenderTransactions[allTenderTransactions.length - 1])

  //write batch array to sheet
  writeToSheet(allTenderTransactions)
  console.log('batch complete')
    }
   }
  }
```

Comment: Nice follow up! Could you explain what you did wrong to help other people who might find this question later?